# Jmeter - Extract multiple values from SOAP response and give that value as input to other SOAP request

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter. I am hitting a web service and getting a SOAP response as below.

SOAP response :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:getResponse ............>
         <ns1:return>
            <ns2:Config ..........>
                .........
                .........
               <ns2:id>1</ns2:id>
               .........
               .........
            </ns2:Config>
            <ns2:Config .........>
               .........
                .........
               <ns2:id>2</ns2:id>
               .........
               .........
            </ns2:Config>
         </ns1:return>
      </ns1:getResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to get these two id values ( ) from both the tags ( ) and give that as input to other SOAP request through loop.

I have tried this by using Regular Expression Extractor.

Reference name : id

Regular Expression : (.+?)

Template : $1$

After which used the ForEach controller and gave the input taken from extractor.

Input variable prefix : id

Output variable name : idValue

And tried to use this idValue to next SOAP request. But not getting the id value in the Regular Expression extractor step itself due to which the second SOAP request is not going at all.

Any suggestions on this would be highly helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Any feedback on this ?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Regular Expression Extractor, I have added the Match no as -1 which solved my problem.

Reference name : id

Regular Expression : `<ns2:id>(.+?)</ns2:id>`

Template : $1$

Match No. : -1

In foreach Controller, I gave the same details.

Input variable prefix : id

Output variable name : idValue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should rather user:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion

It uses XPath syntax :

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath

You can test your XPath queries in View Results Tree using XPath Tester